# SemanticUI menu - first item always active

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am rebuilding my portfolio in React, and while setting up the menu that I am using from semantic UI, I observe that the first menu item is always active.
I am fairly new to React, and this is my first project on the same.

So, here's my Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Here's my App.js

```
import "./main.css";
import React from "react";
import { Route, NavLink, BrowserRouter as HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import home from "./home";
import about from "./about";
import portfolio from "./portfolio";
import resume from "./resume";
import contactMe from "./contactMe";

class mainContent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div className="main-content">
          <div className="ui five item menu">
            <NavLink to="/" className="item">
              Home
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/about" className="item">
              About
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/portfolio" className="item">
              Portfolio
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/resume" className="item">
              Resume
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/contactMe" className="item">
              Contact Me
            </NavLink>
          </div>

          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={about} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" component={portfolio} />
            <Route path="/resume" component={resume} />
            <Route path="/contactMe" component={contactMe} />
          </div>
          <div className="footer">
            <footer className="fixed">
              &copy; Credits
            </footer>
          </div>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default mainContent;
```

everything looks fine, except that first item does not seem to loose the active status when navigated to different component.

Here's an image that you can refer to -
[image]

How can I solve this issue? so that only the current link is shown as active.
Appreciate your help and feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `exact` prop on the `NavLink` components too. The root route `/` is always going to match because it is the root route.

This is what you need to add

```
<NavLink to="/" className="item" exact>Home</NavLink>
```